# Can i connect an Arduino device to a flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, arduino, iot

I want to develop an android mobile application using flutter for the front-end and I will also have a database.
Then I want to connect my application to an Arduino device I made (a smart wristband with a GPRS module, heart rate, and temperature sensors). Is it possible to connect my device to the application? And how?
How can I send the data from my device to the application and vice versa? Should I choose something easier to work with other than flutter and what can i use?
I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your Arduino device with flutter using a Bluetooth module.
[Video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofm1oyJZlmQ)